# Snowflake retry failed tasks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a scheduled snowflake task, which occasionally fails due to delay in upstream data availability. Is it possible to set it to automatically retry it n times in case of a failure.

If this feature is available we can directly use snowflake task scheduling instead of relying on external schedulers

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can check some condition from inside of Snowflake, you can accomplish something like what you need.

There's a WHEN clause to check a condition for a task. If the WHEN clause evaluates to true, then the task runs. Otherwise, it doesn't run.

There's also a parameter that specifies if a task can run overlapping ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION.

Let's say your task runs once an hour and normally takes a minute to complete. You can set:

```
SCHEDULE = '5 minutes'
ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION = false
WHEN = datediff(minute, <condition to check goes here> , current_timestamp()) > 60
```

As far as the , you could do something simple like this:

```
create or replace table LAST_SUCCESSFUL_JOB_MYJOB(COMPLETION_TIME timestamp default current_timestamp);

insert into LAST_SUCCESSFUL_JOB_MYJOB (COMPLETION_TIME) values (current_timestamp);

-- Run this on completion of successful job run by the MYJOB task:
update LAST_SUCCESSFUL_JOB_MYJOB set COMPLETION_TIME = current_timestamp;

-- You should then be able to use something like this to test if the last 
-- successful job is older than 60 minutes.
select datediff(minute, (select COMPLETION_TIME from LAST_SUCCESSFUL_JOB_MYJOB limit 1), current_timestamp()) > 60;
```